# WooCommerce: Set minimum order amount for just specific product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I need to force a minimum order amount for just some categories in WooCommerce, and therefore set an alert in the cart and checkout pages.

So far I managed to set an alert if the total amount in the cart is lower than the minimum amount set, but I can't manage to create a category based filter. Actually any other product is added in the cart the alert is overtaken and the user is allowed to buy the product of that category I want to limit.

Here is the code:

```
/**
 * Set a minimum order amount for checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
 
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 30;
    // set array with cat IDs
    $category_ids = array( 336, 427, 433 );
    // set bool that checks is minimum amount has been reached
    $needs_minimum_amount = false; // Initializing

    $subTotal_amount = WC()->cart->subtotal; // Items subtotal including taxes
    $total_amount = WC()->cart->total; // Items subtotal excluding taxes

            if ( $total_amount < $minimum ) { 
              
              // Loop through cart items
              foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
                $product_id   = $cart_item['product_id'];
                $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id']; 

                // Check for matching product categories
                  if( sizeof($category_ids) > 0 ) {
                      $taxonomy = 'product_cat';
                      if ( has_term( $category_ids, $taxonomy, $product_id ) ) { 
                          $needs_minimum_amount = true;
                          break; // Stop the loop
                      }
                  }
              }

              if( $needs_minimum_amount ) {

                  if( is_cart()) {

                    wc_print_notice( 
                        sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' , 
                            wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                            wc_price( $minimum )
                        ), 'error' 
                    );

                  } else {

                    wc_add_notice( 
                        sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order' , 
                            wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                            wc_price( $minimum )
                        ), 'error' 
                    );

                  }

              }
    }
}
```

References:

- [Set minimum Order amount for specific Products or Categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37267349/set-minimum-order-amount-for-specific-products-or-categories-in-woocommerce)
- https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code… Use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $min_amount = 30; // Min subtotal required
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat'; // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
    $terms      = array( 336, 427, 433 ); // Category terms (can be Ids, slugs, or names)
    $found      = false; // Initializing

    $subtotal   = WC()->cart->subtotal; // Incl. taxes
    $total      = WC()->cart->total; // Incl. taxes

    if ( $total < $min_amount ) { 
        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            if ( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) { 
                $found = true;
                break; // Stop the loop
            }
            
            if( $found ) {
                $message = sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' , 
                    wc_price( $total ), 
                    wc_price( $min_amount )
                );
                
                if( is_cart()) {
                    wc_print_notice( $message, 'error' );
                } else {
                    wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). It should work.

---

**Addition: Based on specific subtotal incl. taxes**

This code version is based on items subtotal belonging to specific defined categories:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $min_amount = 30; // Min subtotal required
    $taxonomy   = 'product_cat'; // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
    $terms      = array( 336, 427, 433 ); // Category terms (can be Ids, slugs, or names)
    
    $subtotal   = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( $terms, $taxonomy, $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];
        }
    }

    if ( $subtotal < $min_amount ) {
        if( $found ) {
            $message = sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' ,
                wc_price( $total ),
                wc_price( $min_amount )
            );

            if( is_cart()) {
                wc_print_notice( $message, 'error' );
            } else {
                wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It should works.

Comment: Hello LoicTheAztec! first of all thank you very much for your answer!
Unfortunately there's still something wrong in the code :(
Actually putting the if condition in the foreach loop made the functions stop working at all. 
Instead, putting the if condition outiste the foreach made the function working bad as before: the alert is shown but it doesn't recognize the category filter (keeping adding products of other categories to the cart allows the checkout to the user)!
Any idea of what is going wrong?

Comment: @Stefano Oups! my fault! replaced `dd_action` with `add_action` at the beginning of the code… It should work.

Comment: thanks again for your time! I think to have actually understood why the code is not running as expected.
The variable $total takes into accont the whole amount in the cart, regarless of the products into it. For that reason, keeping adding product of other categories makes the alert go away even if the total amount of the products I want to target (the ones having a certain category) is still below the $min amount set.
What I'd need is to check the total amount only of the products having that term (whose ids are included in the $terms variable).
Any idea to reach that goal?

Comment: I had to to work a little on your code (some variables/conditions were missing) but in the end i found the solution! 
I'll write it below in case it can help someone else out there, many thanks indeed, i really appreciated it!

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the solution working a little on the code provided by @LoicTheAztec.

Below the final code. Tested and working.

```
// Set a minimum order amount for checkout
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
// add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
 
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $min_amount = 30; // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $taxonomies = array('product_cat'); // Product category taxonomy | For product tags use 'product_tag'
    $term_ids = array( 336, 427, 433 ); // Category terms (can be Ids, slugs, or names)
  
    $found = false; // Initializing // set bool that checks if minimum amount has been reached
    
    $subtotal  = 0; // Initializing // set subtotal formed by specific category total (incl. taxes)
    $subTotal_amount = WC()->cart->subtotal; // Items subtotal including taxes
    $total_amount = WC()->cart->total; // Items subtotal including taxes    

    // 1 - Loop through cart items targeting those having that specific category
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        if ( has_term( $term_ids, $taxonomies[0], $cart_item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $subtotal += $cart_item['line_subtotal'] + $cart_item['line_subtotal_tax'];                      
        }
    }

    // 2 - Check if at least one product of that category is in the cart
    if($subtotal > 0){
      $found = true;
    }

    // 2 - check if subtotal is below the min amount set
     if ( $subtotal < $min_amount ) { 

            if( $found ) {

                $message = sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' , 
                    wc_price( $subtotal ), 
                    wc_price( $min_amount )
                );

                if( is_cart()) {

                  wc_print_notice( $message, 'error' );

                } else {

                  wc_add_notice( $message, 'error' );

                }

            
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: First your question was not clear enough, and my first answer was answering your initial question and working for it… Then you have changed your initial question and you have made your answer here based on my answer code addition. This is not the right way to do things and it is really not fair… So I will not answer your questions  anymore.