# Remove specific products from WooCommerce cart under certain amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I'm trying to remove 2 membership products from cart under 200 in cart total, based on [Set minimum Order amount for specific Products or Categories in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37267979/11987538) answer code, this is the script:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
 
function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    $minimum_amount = 200;
    $category_ids   = array( 83 ); 
    $product_ids    = array( 1111 , 1112 ); 


    if( WC()->cart->is_empty() || ! ( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) ) 
        return; 

    $total_amount = WC()->cart->subtotal; // Items subtotal including taxes

    if ( $total_amount < $minimum_amount ) {
        $needs_minimum_amount = false; 

        // Loop through cart items
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $product_id   = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
            
            if( sizeof($category_ids) > 0 ) {
                $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

                if ( has_term( $category_ids, $taxonomy, $product_id ) ) { 
                    $needs_minimum_amount = true;
                    break; // Stop the loop
                }
            }

            if( sizeof($product_ids) > 0 ) {
                if ( array_intersect( $product_ids, array($product_id, $variation_id) ) ) { 
                    $needs_minimum_amount = true;
                    break; 
                }
            }
        }

        if( $needs_minimum_amount ) {
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        if ( $cart_item['product_id'] == 1111 || $cart_item['product_id'] == 1112 ) {
            WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
            }
    }   
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 
                __("רכישת חברת מועדון מעל %s. כרגע סך העגלה שלך עומד על %s."), 
                wc_price( $minimum_amount ), 
                wc_price( $total_amount )
            ), 'error' );
    


        }
    }
}
```

For some reason the products aren't removed from the cart but the notice is working, anyone has a clue what am I missing?

See website-> https://woocommerce-620267-2036098.cloudwaysapps.com/

Comment: Have you looked at your log files yet? do these contain an error message? You mention removing products. However, there is also a part that takes the category into account. Does this also apply?

Comment: From what I read online remove_cart_item() doesn't require category

Comment: Then why is it used in your code? if it is not required?

Comment: Its required to determine if the product needs minimum amount

Comment: I just dont understand why the remove_cart_item() isnt working :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a few bugs and a wrong hook as well, also I've simplified it for you given you only need to check against product IDs:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout', 'bbloomer_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart', 'bbloomer_minimum_order_amount' );
 
function bbloomer_minimum_order_amount() {
    $minimum_amount = 200;
    $product_ids = array( 186181, 186185 ); 
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) return; 
    $total_amount = WC()->cart->subtotal; // Items subtotal including taxes
    if ( $total_amount < $minimum_amount ) {
        $needs_minimum_amount = false; 
        foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
            $product_id = $cart_item['product_id'];
            $variation_id = $cart_item['variation_id'];
            if ( array_intersect( $product_ids, array( $product_id, $variation_id ) ) ) { 
                $needs_minimum_amount = true;
                break; 
            }
        }
        if ( $needs_minimum_amount ) {
            foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
                if ( array_intersect( $product_ids, array( $cart_item['product_id'], $cart_item['variation_id'] ) ) ) {
                    WC()->cart->remove_cart_item( $cart_item_key );
                }
            }
            wc_print_notice( sprintf( 
                __("רכישת חברת מועדון מעל %s. כרגע סך העגלה שלך עומד על %s."), 
                wc_price( $minimum_amount ), 
                wc_price( $total_amount )
            ), 'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, I need to remove the products 1111 and 1112 from the cart and i don't understand why it doesnt remove them

Comment: Yes - did you put those IDs inside $product_ids?